# Can I write in java for facebook wall read?

Tags: java, facebook

I want to read the facebook stream of the user via a java client/program.

Is it possible? If yes, any pointers on a how to doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [facebook-java-api](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/)

Comment: This is dead as of 2013.  Please use the other answer, restfb

Answer (score 2):

yes, possible. See the [framework](http://restfb.com/).

Comment: Well you can try to implement things yourself which will take longer. Why dont you want to use the framework?